# Is there a way to use view pager in Xamarin.Form?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

Xamarin.Form have this `CarouselPage` built in. But it seems that there's no way it's like view pager in native android implement(with no cache, have to create all pages before it actually presented).

So I'm wondering if there's a way to use view pager with Xamarin.Form, or to custom CarouselPage to act like one.

Comment: You will probably need to implement a custom renderer which fits your need.

Comment: @Cheesebaron Thanks for your answer.Do you mean like extends the `CarouselPage` class and change some of it's behavior? I've tried this, but there's only a `CurrentPageChanged` event there, with no indication of which way did user swiped(forwards of backwards). Maybe I should try override some of it's rendering method

Comment: No, Implement a Custom Renderer using a ViewPager.

Comment: @Cheesebaron So I have to use the native android `ViewPager` instead of Xamarin.Forms? How to make these two work together?